# No access to root thru su

Tags: linux-mint, root, su

I'm trying to access my PC as root

```
su
```

and it doesn't says root@something
it says

```
mypcname username # vi /something/
```

and in the normal terminal display says

```
username@mypcname ~ $
```

someone that knows what is happening?
I need to gain access to a folder.

- Linux mint 13 maya
- cinnamon 64-bits
- intel centrino inside
- pc OS full mint with no partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Claudius indicates, whoami will likely give you a different answer, and doing a login shell will also likely change things.

The "#" in the path indicates you are root.  The username in the prompt comes from the $USER variable. Since you didn't su as a login shell, it did not replace the environment.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami

Comment: isn't it supposed to appear as root???

Comment: Not necessarily. The username there really reflects what user set up the environment. So, if it shows "ashutko" I know that I have ashutko's path, ashutko's USER variable, and any other environment variables I have set up as ashutko. The $ in the prompt changes to a # to indicate you are root, but there are reasons you might want to select either environment to work in.

If it says root, I know that it nuked my user's environment and initialized it based on root's profile.  That's what happens when you du a su - .

Answer (score 1):

Try `whoami` to know who you actually are (legend has it Microsoft removed this command in one of their releases because they assumed users always remembered). The name in your prompt (and probably the largest part of the prompt itself) is inherited from your previous shell, as you did not start a new login shell (cf. [Alan Shutko’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/486518/163736)).

You might also want to try `su -` to get a full login shell and see if the prompt changes there.

Comment: ..and if `su -` doesn't work you can try `su - root`

Comment: it says that I'm root but still I'm unable to access a folder, it says access denied...

Comment: Is this folder part of a FUSE filesystem mounted by a user? They sometimes have the nasty property of denying access to root. Furthermore, what is the output of `id`? Hopefully starting with `uid=0(root)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo su` ? It works like this on my debian. Not sure about mint, but should work.